# existing function is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I am working with a hammer.js library: http://hammerjs.github.io/ and using its jQuery plugin. There are few ivents like 'panright panleft press' on occurrence of which you are able to call a function. I am trying to call a cardSwipe(..) function, however get a consol error saying that cardSwipe is undefined. I can't figure out what is causing this.

```
/* Initiate HammerJS on elements */
        initHammer : function()
        {   
            /* Create Hammer object for swipable game cards */
            Game.$gameCard = $('.game-card-mobile');
            Game.$gameCardTouch = Game.$gameCard.hammer();

            Game.$gameCardTouch.on("panleft panright press", cardSwipe(ev, $(this), data));     
        },

        cardSwipe : function(ev, element, data) {
            console.log(ev.type);
            console.log(element);
            console.log(data);
        }
```

Edit: adding Game.cardSwipe resolved that, but now I get an error of: ev is undefined, where ev is a hammer.js event and should be recognized (it is if I swap my function to function(ev) {..} )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `cardSwipe` really is undefined in that context, it's part of the parent object and is accessed with `this.cardSwipe`

```
initHammer : function() {   
    Game.$gameCard = $('.game-card-mobile');
    Game.$gameCardTouch = Game.$gameCard.hammer();

    Game.$gameCardTouch.on("panleft panright press", this.cardSwipe(ev, $(this), data));     
},
cardSwipe : function(ev, element, data) {
    console.log(ev.type);
    console.log(element);
    console.log(data);
}
```

It also looks like you're calling it right away, not referencing it, generally you would convert it to something like this

```
Game.$gameCardTouch.on("events", this.cardSwipe);
```

or if you need the arguments, use an anonymous function

```
initHammer : function() {   

    var self = this;

    Game.$gameCardTouch.on("panleft panright press", function() {
        self.cardSwipe(ev, $(self), data);
    });
},
cardSwipe : function(ev, element, data) {

}
```

But I have no idea what `cardSwipe` really returns, and how this is supposed to work ?

Comment: Yes this was an issue, resolved it and am now getting one in edit. I will accept your answer once I can.

Comment: As to your last edit, what card swipe will do is print event type 'ev.type' of hammer.js so say panright or one of other three. This worked when I used function(ev) { } instead of cardSwipe, but now ev is undefined, also print element details of that one which an event was performed on and data (defined before)

Answer (score 2):

In your code the `cardSwipe` function is a property of some object.  You will have to use that object reference as in:

```
obj.cardSwipe(...)
```

in order to call it - where `obj` is the object that contains the property.

I don't know the entire context of your code, but it appears that the appropriate reference might be:

```
this.cardSwipe(...);
```

since you're calling it from a method of the same object.

---

Unlike some other languages, methods on the current object are not automatically in scope.  You must use `this` to refer to the current object to access a property or call a method on the current object.

---

In addition, it looks like you're trying to set up an event handler.  In that case, you would want to not call `cardSwipe()` immediately, but pass a function reference instead and you would need to save the value of `this` into a local so you can reference it in the callback:

```
initHammer : function() {   
    var self = this;
    Game.$gameCard = $('.game-card-mobile');
    Game.$gameCardTouch = Game.$gameCard.hammer();

    Game.$gameCardTouch.on("panleft panright press", function() {
        self.cardSwipe(ev, $(self), data));
    });
},
```